# IPv6 connections routed to IPv4 device

Tags: routing, ipv6, ipv4, legacy

I have an IBM 9406-250 with V5R1 and IPv4 only connectivity, and want it to be reachable over IPv6. I cannnot install an IPv6 stack on it, but I want it to be accessible by IPv6 so I can drop the requirement to VPN to my home network.

I have an OpenWRT device running, which takes care of the IPv6 routing on my network and the tunnel to SIXXS, and I was wondering if it is possible to assign another IPv6 address to that device, and route it to the IPv4 IBM computer.

Which software do I need for this, and how is this technique called?

Edit:

One port would be sufficient actually, would it be possible to add an extra IP to the interface of the OpenWRT box, and redirect port 23 from the AS/400 to port 23 on the IPv6 IP?

Comment: No idea if it supports it, but have a look at [NAT64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64).

Comment: I'm looking for the reverse of this: connect IPv6 clients to an IPv4 host, if I understand correctly this allows me to connect to IPv4 hosts from an IPv6 only network?

Comment: I know that it's the opposite of what you want, which is why I don't know if it'll work. You may be able to configure it in a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I editted the question to make myself more clear, I don't want to put the entire IPv4 subnet IPv6 reachable this way, one port would be enough actually. I currently have an SSH tunnel setup which connects to localhost, and redirects the port 23 to IPv6...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to relay packets, for example:

```
socat TCP6-LISTEN:23,fork TCP4:192.168.0.10:23
```

Answer (score 0):

[IPv6 support is available as of V5R2](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS202-123). If you can update, that might be an easy solution.

Another option is to place the beast behind a [NAT64/DNS64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64) gateway. You may need a different device, as the last time I looked, NAT64 was not well supported on OpenWrt.